# How do you use multiple Google Fonts in a webpage?

Tags: css, html

I know this is a short question, but how do you use multiple custom Google Fonts, i.e Baloo and Roboto, in the text?
In this example the text should be Roboto and headings should be Baloo.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 21):

You click "select this font" for each font you want to use, and google will give you a single `link` tag with multiple fonts. You can also include multiple `link` tags for each font.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: Baloo;
}
h2 {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<h1>Baloo</h1>
<h2>Roboto</h2>
```

Comment: Wow never realized that you can get multiple familys in one request.

Comment: @WebDevGuy yah it's a kinda newish thing, I think they started doing it around a year ago.

Comment: Knowing that the pipe symbol `'|'` is the way to add multiple font families is very useful! Can you also choose what sizes or boldnesses to apply to all the fonts in your #pipeSeparated list (e.g., `300, 400, 700`)?

Comment: @EricHepperle-CodeSlayer2010 Yes, you can use multiple font weights on the same google font:

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500|900

Exact as you say.

Answer (score 9):

google fonts is now using css2 and the answers above are outdated.

the solution using css2 would be:
`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Baloo&family=Roboto`

source: [google fonts doc for css2](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2)

Comment: I'm trying this in 2023 and it does not currently work.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to https://fonts.google.com/
2. Search for say Roboto - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto
3. Hit "select this font" and you'll get a link to add to you html like this:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">`

Note: You can also get one line with multiple fonts by piping the families.

4. Add this link(s) in your `<head>` tag
5. Use CSS to select the font with `font-family`.

See example below:

```css
h1{
  font-family: "Baloo"
}

p{
  font-family: "Roboto"
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo|Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Baloo</h1>
    <p>Roboto</p>
</body>
```

Comment: You can include multiple font families in one call by pipe-separating the families -- `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo|Roboto`.

Comment: Just tried it in 2023... and confirm it works well :) thank you

Answer (score -1):

Use as many as you want and import them as a stylesheet.
https://fonts.google.com/

For your example:

```css
h1 { font-family: 'Baloo', cursive; }
p { font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif; }
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Baloo" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<h1>heading</h1>
<p>paragraph</p>
```